# The Job History web server can't connect to the Resource Manager in a HA setup

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

When using the YARN Resource Manager webapp, I have a problem viewing a page with job history, with URL like this:

`http://node-0002.example.com:19888/jobhistory/job/job_1455545464819_0001`

It shows a HTTP error with a Java exception like this:

````
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: node-0001.example.com,node-0002.example.com:8088 (configuration property 'yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address')
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.YarnConfiguration.getSocketAddr(YarnConfiguration.java:1782)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.util.WebAppUtils.getResolvedRMWebAppURLWithoutScheme(WebAppUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AppController.<init>(AppController.java:63)```
````

The hostname `node-0001.example.com,node-0002.example.com` is obviously wrong.

I have a pretty straightforward HA-enabled configuration in my `yarn-site.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id</name>
    <value>my-cluster</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.rm-ids</name>
    <value>node-0001.example.com,node-0002.example.com</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.node-0001.example.com</name>
    <value>node-0001.example.com</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.node-0002.example.com</name>
    <value>node-0002.example.com</value>
</property>
```

The only unusual thing is naming the `rm-id`s in the same way as the hosts. I also tried defining properties like `yarn.resourcemanager.address` and `yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address`, but that didn't help.

Any idea where the comma-separated list instead of a hostname is coming from? I use Hadoop 2.7.1.